# Derivative and length of a curve

Tags: calculus

Let $\alpha:[a;b]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector function with 1 argument $\alpha$ different from$(0,0)$.Find the derivative of :
$$ \phi(t)=\ln(\|\alpha(t)\|)+\langle b,\alpha(t)\rangle$$
where $b=(2,3)$.Find the length of parametric curve given by:

$$\alpha(t)=(\cos t+t\sin t, \sin t-t\cos t)$$ where $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Use TeX `\to` instead of 'minus, greater than' for a short right arrow: $\to$, and `\langle .\rangle` for angle brackets: $\langle .\rangle$. Prefix logs and trig functions with a backslash: `\ln, \log, \sin, \cos`  to make them look like function names: $\ln, \log, \sin, \cos$, not 'ell times en' or 'cee times o times es'.

Comment: Thank you,nice tip.I will edit.Any suggestions about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: the derivative of $\|\alpha(t)\|$ in $b$ is $\langle b, \alpha'(t)\rangle/\|\alpha(t)\|$; now apply chain rule.

Hint 2: $\|\alpha'(t)\|^2=t^2$, now integrate.